# A linux machine with lots of processes in uninterruptible sleep state

Tags: ubuntu, process, zombie

I have a linux machine that has lots of processes in *uninterruptible sleep* state.

I'd like to know why this happens.

Here's part of the information of running `top -o S` command:

```
top - 14:44:51 up 298 days,  4:47,  1 user,  load average: 84.54, 85.11, 85.33
Tasks: 622 total,   1 running, 621 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 11.5 us,  2.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 85.6 id,  0.5 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.3 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:  32905924 total, 28823880 used,  4082044 free,   975272 buffers
KiB Swap: 33517564 total,  8570164 used, 24947400 free. 14813544 cached Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 2153 root      20   0   22904   1156    944 D   0.0  0.0   0:00.01 ps
 2425 root      20   0    4372    712    532 D   0.0  0.0   0:00.01 pidof
 4148 root      20   0    4372    712    532 D   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 pidof
 6608 user1      20   0   14504    844    724 D   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ps
 7103 user1      20   0   14504    828    724 D   0.0  0.0   0:00.01 ps
 7672 user1      20   0   14504    844    724 D   0.0  0.0   0:00.01 ps
 8081 user1      20   0   14504    772    668 D   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ps
12816 root      20   0   22904   1168    960 D   0.0  0.0   0:00.01 ps
13720 user1      20   0   14504    884    716 D   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ps
14854 root      20   0   22904   1172    964 D   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ps
17040 1200      20   0 16.078g   5760   4800 D   0.0  0.0   0:00.01 msedgedriver-97
17521 user1      20   0   14504    844    724 D   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ps
17918 user1      20   0   14504    848    724 D   0.0  0.0   0:00.01 ps
19008 root      20   0   14504    848    724 D   0.0  0.0   0:00.01 ps
19926 root      20   0   14504    852    724 D   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 ps
```

The `D` in `S` column means that the process is in *uninterruptible sleep* state.

What might cause the [load average](https://www.javatpoint.com/linux-load-average) to be `84.54, 85.11, 85.33`? This is too high.

Why does `ps` command get stuck?

Here're some information about my machine:

```
$ nproc
8

$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="14.04.5 LTS, Trusty Tahr"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS"
VERSION_ID="14.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"

$ iostat
Linux 3.13.0-123-generic (IOT-CI)   01/12/2023  _x86_64_    (8 CPU)

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           8.80    0.00    1.90    0.64    0.00   88.66

Device:            tps    kB_read/s    kB_wrtn/s    kB_read    kB_wrtn
sda              37.57       164.32      1690.01 4233832157 43543586647
sdb              14.96       239.74       212.36 6177083529 5471449596
sdc               3.62        22.87        35.53  589207209  915440292
dm-0            157.96       127.00      1661.97 3272293073 42821280300
dm-1             16.33        37.27        28.03  960306880  722306144
dm-2             16.33        37.27        28.03  960301900  722306144
```

Here's the content of `/proc/2153/stack`.

```
[<ffffffff813792b4>] call_rwsem_down_read_failed+0x14/0x30
[<ffffffff8117f332>] __access_remote_vm+0x42/0x1d0
[<ffffffff81180120>] access_process_vm+0x50/0x70
[<ffffffff8122ad2a>] proc_pid_cmdline+0x8a/0x120
[<ffffffff8122c00f>] proc_info_read+0x9f/0xf0
[<ffffffff811c2335>] vfs_read+0x95/0x160
[<ffffffff811c2e49>] SyS_read+0x49/0xa0
[<ffffffff8173dd9d>] system_call_fastpath+0x1a/0x1f
[<ffffffffffffffff>] 0xffffffffffffffff
```

2153 is the process id of a `ps` command.

Comment: The CPU load is relatively small, 85% idle. But you have too many  running processes. Check why there are so many `ps` commands running

Comment: I've used `ps` command to view the processes on this machine for many times. But sometimes `ps` get stuck. That's the reason for so many `ps` commands running.

Comment: SO this is the reason of getting big "load average". Maybe you should change your approach or refactor your process for different tool(set).